# How to change mail sender of wp_mail?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I'm trying to change the sender mail address of the mails sent by my wordpress page. Currently the sender is www-data of my server.

I already tried using different Plugins (WP Mail SMTP, CB Change Mail Sender, WP Simple Mail Sender,... ).

I also tried changing the sender via actions as you can see in the following code, which is placed in my child theme's function.php:

```php
function mail_from_address($email)
{
    return 'example@example.com';
}
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'mail_from_address');
function mail_from_name($name)
{
    return 'myname';
}
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'mail_from_name');
```

Since all these ways did not work, I wonder where my mistake could be?

Comment: That sounds like WP Mail SMTP setting problem. What plugin are you using for sending e-mails?

Comment: @Maurice I'm not using a plugin for sending mails, i just send them via wp_mail() function in my code

Comment: If all fails - add it to the `$headers` array in your mail function

Comment: @Stender doesn't work as well